# How to set H2 Database console url in the Quarkus Application

Tags: h2, quarkus

As Spring boot application provides a property to set the web console URL of the H2 Database.

```
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

Is there a way to set this same property in the Quarkus application? If not then what is the default 
 web console URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. But it's not quite as simple as in Spring Boot because Quarkus does not do the same first-class support for H2 as Spring Boot does.

First, you need to [activate Servlet support in Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference). Then, you go ahead and configure the H2 servlet in a `web.xml` deployment descriptor or in a `undertow-handlers.conf` if you're familiar with it.

Here we go:

0. Assuming that you already have the `quarkus-jdbc-h2` extension added
1. Add the `quarkus-vertx` and `quarkus-undertow` extensions
2. Create the deployment descriptor under `src/main/resources/META-INF/web.xml`
3. Configure the H2 console Servlet like so

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>h2-console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>h2-console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/h2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Run `./mvnw quarkus:dev` and go to `http://localhost:8080/h2` where the console should show up.

If you need to set a parameter use `<init-param>` like e.g.:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>h2-console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>webAllowOthers</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    
</servlet>
```

http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#usingH2ConsoleServlet

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thx!