# How to enable the H2 Database Console using Quarkus?

Tags: jakarta-ee, console, h2, quarkus, h2-console

In Spring you would enable the H2 console with

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Is it also possible to enable the console in Quarkus?

Comment: Maybe [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853691/how-to-set-h2-database-console-url-in-the-quarkus-application) might help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Weird that it was not suggested as an existing question and even now trying to mark this one here as a duplicate to the other won't find the other one by it's exact name

Comment: That's probably because the answer is not upvoted at least once and therefore not recognized as a solution to the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set H2 Database console url in the Quarkus Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853691/how-to-set-h2-database-console-url-in-the-quarkus-application)